# JPA repository + @EntityListeners in JUnit tests

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, spring-data-jpa

I have created Entity Listerner

```
public class SomeListener {
    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void someAction(final SomeInterface entity) {
```

And added it to Entitites

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(SomeListener.class)
public class SomeEntity implements SomeInterface {
```

Entities obtained from repository

```
@Repository
public interface SomeRepository
        extends JpaRepository<SomeEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<SomeEntity> {
```

In code it works fine, but in tests this listener is ignored

Test configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {
        "package with listener",
        "package with model",
        "package with repository",
        "and all other packages"
})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
        "packages with repositories"
})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {
        "packages with models"
})
public class TestConfig {
}
```

Abstract class for Integration tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractTestInt {
```

and in test just called

```
mockMvc.perform(post(CREATE_URL).params(someparams))
.andExpect(status().is5xxServerError())
```

Entity listener should check some attributes and throw exception, because provided params wrong, but exception isn't thrown and in debugger I can see that parameters really wrong, so returned status `redirection`, as success save when called `someRepository.save(entity)`

Why Entity Listener not called in test context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here was problem not in tests, in my `@PrePersist`/`@PreUpdate` listener was additional check for access rights and thrown `AccessDeniedException`. When work `@PrePersist` - all is fine, because fired this event immediately, but `@PreUpdate` can be fired later, when transaction or some contexts is closed, and when this check tries to throw exception it tries to rollback transaction, that already closed, so it's causes another exception. For security of application it's okay - update request not sent, but not for tests.

Solution for this problem was in changing of `repository.save()` to `repository.saveAndFlush()` (that immediately causes writing to db and `@PreUpdate` event firing too)